# Serilog sink on ElasticSearch cloud with Kibana not receiving the messages

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, kibana, serilog

I am using latest Serilog with ElasticSink and I have the following configuration:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(elasticUri))
        {
            IndexFormat = "ConsoleAPP-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}",
            AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
            CustomFormatter = new ExceptionAsObjectJsonFormatter(renderMessage: true),
            ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.BasicAuthentication("myusername", "mypassword"),
            EmitEventFailure =
                EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToSelfLog |
                EmitEventFailureHandling.RaiseCallback |
                EmitEventFailureHandling.ThrowException,
            FailureCallback = e => {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to submit event " + e.MessageTemplate);
            }
        })
        .WriteTo.File("Logs/log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
        .CreateLogger();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
}
```

but when I go to Kibana I have two problems. 
1. I don't see an index `ConsoleApp...`. Only an index named `logstash-2020.02.10`
2. Inside this index I see some messages that were written an hour ago. I don't see any new log messages even if there is activity

Update #1: 
Here is how I use it inside a controller

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public TestController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TestController>();
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public string Test()
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Called Test/Test controller method");

        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Comment: Need more info how you declare logger.Maybe this stackoverflow question can fix your problem. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59060106/serilog-not-logging-to-elasticsearch"

Comment: @phonemyatt I have updated my question and added snippet of how I am calling logger

Comment: Have you tried this example? https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/logging-with-elasticsearch-kibana-asp-net-core-and-docker. From what I see, there's nothing wrong with your code. Maybe roll back to normal console log and try to see whether it's working to check is the first step I will try

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you using logger factory. Do you have any custom logger class that you created? At controller, changing to ILogger is equivalent to CreateLogger

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly ILogger<TestController > logger;

    public TestController(ILogger<TestController > _logger)
    {
        logger = _logger;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public string Test()
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Called Test/Test controller method");

        return "ok";
    }
}
```

I also notice you call CreateLogger two times in startup and controller. Is is what causing the issue?